# How do you sell to people who don't know they have a problem?

Tags: marketing, sales, copywriting

I use the "Problem / Agitate / Solution concept" copywriting formula, often with good results. This is a great framework if the problem is obvious (e.g. weight loss), but about problems that people are not aware they have? Or they are too comfortable in their current status and don't think things can be better for them?

**How to best create a sales pitch for people who are unaware they have a problem or are too comfortable with their current status?**

Comment: Can you give us information about what problem you are talking about?

Comment: Career growth in a specific field. Because that industry offers good pay at the bottom, middle and top of the industry, people become confortable, but don't realize that if they would grow, they could make more money, and have more choice of employers and projects they can work on.

Comment: Unless job security becomes an issue, you are unlikely to have much success.  If people are comfortable, they rarely seek change.

Comment: the obvious answer is to make them realize they have a problem and convince them that what they have is not good enough. ie 'you have a computer, but does it have [insert sales point here]?'

Comment: This seems like an overly complicated way of asking someone to sell you a Pen - the tired sales interview question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Medium post](https://medium.com/the-mission/the-greatest-sales-deck-ive-ever-seen-4f4ef3391ba0) does a great job of answering this question, IMO. The short of it is:

**The 5 Elements of a Brilliant Sales Narrative**

1. Name a Big, Relevant Change in the World
2. Show There’ll Be Winners and Losers
3. Tease the Promised Land
4. Introduce Product as “Magic Gifts” for Overcoming Obstacles to the Promised Land
5. Present Evidence that You Can Make the Story Come True

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need!